# React: How do I make Child components in an Array re-render upon prop change?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a MainComponent which has several buttons with different texts. Upon button click the first time for any of them, it'll create a new window component. There is a flag that prevents it from creating more Windows unless this flag changes for some reason (I didn't need to include it here). Assume the code can create multiple Window components and add it to the list and render it successfully, which it does but if the mode is changed, click the buttons again won't create more components.

I render this array of objects by creating an state array and state flag and add new Window component to that array everytime a new one is created and render that array.

My problem is that when new Window create flag is off (flagObj !== null), I click any of the buttons which pass in differing values to the current windows, and I want the values to update. But the values DO NOT update. Each window.body prop accesses this.state.currentWindowData which is what I'm changing everytime a button gets clicked in this mode, and using dev tool I see that the state gets changed accordingly.

For some reason, it is not propagating down to the children Window components in the list. What is the problem?

```
MainComponent
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {renderWindow: false, windowArray: []}
    this.manage= this.manage.bind(this)
}

openWindow() {
   const newWindow = <Window key={shortid.generate()} body={this.state.currentWindowData}/>;
    this.setState({
        renderWindow: true, 
        windowArray: [newWindow, ...this.state.windowArray]
     })
}

modify(val) {
    this.setState({currentWindowData: val});
}

manageWindow(val) {
    if (flagObj === null) {
        this.setState({currentWindowData: val}, () => {
            this.openWindow();
        });
    } else {    
        this.modifyWindow();
    }
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick = {() => this.manage("text1")}/>
        <button onClick = {() => this.manage("text2")}/>
        <button onClick = {() => this.manage("text3")}/>
        {this.state.renderWindow ? this.state.windowArray : null}
      </div>
    )
}
```

This is the window component. I render this.props.body (the state data passed in) and also do this.props.bodyData (set from componentWillReceiveProps), but neither update.

```
Window
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({bodyData: nextProps.body});
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.body}   
            {this.state.bodyData}
        </div> 
    );
}
```